# Clearing textboxes after AJAX success

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm confused as to why this is not working. I simply would like to clear the textboxes after the request success. Is my function within the success set up wrong? I'm fairly new to using AJAX and JavaScript, so any advice would be great!
Here is the full function to to give more perspective on the overall functionality.

```
function txtChk() {
    var controls = 0;
    /* ----------------------------------------------- 
     DECLARING OBJECTS TO HOLD ALL CONTROLS
    ----------------------------------------------- */
    const labels = document.getElementsByClassName('inputLabel');
    const texts = document.getElementsByClassName('gezza-field');
    var rdbYes = document.getElementById("<%=rdbYes.ClientID%>");
    var rdbNo = document.getElementById("<%=rdbNo.ClientID%>");
    var rdbYesLead = document.getElementById("<%=rdbYesLead.ClientID%>");
    var rdbNoLead = document.getElementById("<%=rdbNoLead.ClientID%>");
    var first = document.getElementById("<%=txtFirst.ClientID%>");
    var last = document.getElementById("<%=txtLast.ClientID%>");
    var phone = document.getElementById("<%=txtPhone.ClientID%>");
    var email = document.getElementById("<%=txtEmail.ClientID%>");
    const radiosRef = document.getElementsByClassName('referral');
    const radiosLead = document.getElementsByClassName('lead');

    /*--------------------------------------------------------
       RUNNING FOR LOOPS THROUGH DECLARED OBJECTS TO 
       HANDLE ANY ERRORS (TERNARY OPERATORS INSIDE FORS)
       (SECOND EDIT)
     ------------------------------------------------------- */
     for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         labels[i].style.color = (texts[i].value == "" ? "FireBrick" : "Black");
         labels[i].innerHTML = (texts[i].value == "" && 
         labels[i].innerHTML.charAt(0) != "*" ? "*" + labels[i].innerHTML : labels[i].innerHTML);
        }
    labels[4].innerHTML = (rdbYesLead.checked == false && rdbNoLead.checked == false ? "*Please select one" : "");
    controls = (rdbYesLead.checked == false && rdbNoLead.checked == false ? controls : controls + 1);

    labels[5].innerHTML = (rdbYes.checked == false && rdbNo.checked == false ? "*Please select one" : "");
    controls = (rdbYes.checked == false && rdbNo.checked == false ? controls : controls + 1);

    for (var l = 0; l < 4; l++) {
        if (texts[l].value != "") {
            controls += 1;
        }
    }
    if (controls < 6) {
        alert("Fix all errors before submitting");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var referral = rdbYes.checked == true ? 1 : 0;
        var lead = rdbYesLead.checked == true ? 1 : 0;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Default.aspx/updateDB",
                data: "{'first':'" + first.value + "','last':'" + last.value + "','phone':'" + phone.value + "','email':'" + email.value + "','referral':'" + referral + "','lead':'" + lead + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("Thank you, " + first.value + "!");
                    first.value = "";
                    last.value = "";
                    phone.value = "";
                    email.value = "";
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error! Connection was lost, please try again");
                    }
                });


            //first.value = "";
            //last.value = "";
            //phone.value = "";
            //email.value = "";
            //rdbNo.checked = false;
            //rdbYes.checked = false;
            //rdbNoLead.checked = false;
            //rdbYesLead.checked = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you've shown should work fine, presuming the AJAX request is actually being sent and is successful. Where are you defining the `first`, `last` etc. variables?

Comment: Also note that you can just pass the object to `data`; you don't need to concatenate the huge ugly string.

Comment: And the request is successful because the alert appears, but controls do not clear. This is why I am confused...

Comment: That isn't valid JSON you are trying to send. Don't manually create it yourself... it is more work and error prone compared to serializing objects/arrays using JSON.stringify

Comment: Is this ajax inside a form submit? Show more code context and also check if page is reloading. See [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl I've updated the post to now display the full function.